# Memory alignment today and 20 years ago

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

In the famous paper "Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit", its author takes a C function

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
  char buffer1[5];
  char buffer2[10];
}
```

and generates the corresponding assembly code output

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
subl $20,%esp
```

The author explains that since computers address memory in multiples of word size, the compiler reserved 20 bytes on the stack (8 bytes for buffer1, 12 bytes for buffer2).

I tried to recreate this example and got the following

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $16, %esp
```

A different result! I tried various combinations of sizes for buffer1 and buffer2, and it seems that modern gcc does not pad buffer sizes to multiples of word size anymore. Instead it abides the `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` option.

As an illustration -- using the paper's arithmetic rules, for buffer1[5] and buffer2[13] I'd get 8+16 = 24 bytes reserved on the stack. But in reality I got 32 bytes.

The paper is quite old and a lot of stuff happened since. I'd like to know, what exactly motivated this change of behavior? Is it the move towards 64bit machines? Or something else?

**Edit**

The code is compiled on a x86_64 machine using gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) like that:

`$ gcc -S -o example1.s example1.c -fno-stack-protector -m32`

Comment: 8 + 16 is 24, not 20. By the way, it seems likely that the compiler just got a little bit smarter, its local variable analysis pass considered both char arrays, and since char arrays don't need any alignment, it just stuck them together, and aligned the resulting "compact" array.

Comment: Is there any point in aligning `char` values anyway?

Comment: is this on x86, or x86_64?

Comment: can't speak to this but I'm interested in the answer. I do wonder if it has to do with an optimization since created to solve this problem or the 64 bit-ness of things.

Comment: I wonder if it would align the bottom of the stack if you made that function call an external function to follow an ABI stack alignment requirement. The alignment might be getting optimized away in a leaf function. (Not that reserving a few bytes of stack you don't use would often be a problem, but eh)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: you might be surprised how often some bytes of stack _do_ present a problem; at least if they accumulate. There are much more embedded systems with limited ressources out there than PCs without (or with relaxed limits).

Comment: @Olaf: This is why I said "often", not "always". Very memory limited systems usually don't have gigantic alignment or other similar requirements either (aligning everything to 16 bytes would waste terrible amounts of memory!). And no, I'm not surprised by the fact as I was working with a system with 512 bytes of memory just yesterday.

Comment: Well, actually, you postualated it would not ne often, I tried to clraify it is exactly the other way around. And, yes, there is quite some demand for alignment, expecially as embedded MCUs often do not allow a value to be unaligned. This is true for most smaller AMRs, for instance (whereas the Cortex-M might allow for this, it is a performance issue). Notet that we are talking in padding in general, not just for 128 bits or so. And, yes, I do know very well. Btw: a system with 512 bytes would not require alignment, as it would be an 8 bit system at most, but we are talking about 32bitters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What has changed is [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), which requires 16 byte alignment, this is covered in this older gcc document for [-mpreferred-stack-boundary=num](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> On Pentium and PentiumPro, double and long double values should be aligned to an 8 byte boundary (see -malign-double) or suffer significant run time performance penalties. **On Pentium III, the Streaming SIMD Extension (SSE) data type __m128 suffers similar penalties if it is not 16 byte aligned.**

This is also backed up by the paper [Smashing The Modern Stack For Fun And Profit](https://www.ethicalhacker.net/columns/heffner/smashing-the-modern-stack-for-fun-and-profit) which covers this an other modern changes that break *Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit*.

Answer (score 2):

Memory alignment of which stack alignment is just one aspect depends on the architecture. It is partly defined in the Applicaion Binary Interface of the language and a Procedure Call Standard (sometimes it is both in a single spec) for the architecture (CPU, it might even vary depending on platform) and also depends on the compiler/toolchain where the former documents leave room for variations.

The former two documents (names may vary) are mostly for the external interface between functions; they might leave internal structure to the toolchain. Howwever, that has to match the architecture. Normally the hardware requires a minimal alignment, but allows for a larger alignment for performance reasons (e.g.: byte-alignment minimum, but this would require multiple bus-cycles to read a 32 bit word, so the compiler uses a 32 bit alignment).

Normally, the compiler (following the PCS) uses an alignment optimal for the architecture and under control of optimization settings (optimize for speed or size). It takes into account not only the size of the object (aligned to its natural boundary), but also sizes of internal busses (e.g. a 32 bit x86 has internal 64 or 128 bit busses, ARM CPUs have internal 32 to 128 (possibly even wider) bit busses), caches, etc. For local variables, it may also take into account access-patterns, so two adjacent variables may be loaded in parallel into a register pair instead of two separate loads or even reorder such variables.

The stackpointer might require a higher alignment for instance, so the CPU can push in an interrupt frame two registers at once, push vector registers which require higher alignment, etc. You can write quite a thick book about this subject (and I bet, someone already has).

So, in general, there is no single one-alignment-fits all rule. However, for struct and array packing, the C standard *does* define some rules for packing/alignment, mostly to guarantee consistence of e.g. sizeof(type) and the address in an array (required for correct `malloc()`).

Even char arrays might be aligned for optimal cache layout. Note it is not only the CPU which might have caches, but also PCIe bridges, not to mention PCIe transfers themselves down to DRAM pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that specific version of compiler or the distribution version you report. My guess would be the 16 is from byte alignment requirements on stack (i.e. all stack adjustments would be x byte aligned and x may be 16 for your invocation).

Note that variable alignment you seem to have started with, is slightly different from the above and is controlled by align markings on the variable in gcc. Try using those and you should see a difference.