# Smashing the stack example3 ala Aleph One

Tags: c, security, pointers, stack-smash

I've reproduced Example 3 from [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) on Linux x86_64. However I'm having trouble understanding what is the correct number of bytes that should be incremented to the return address in order to skip past the instruction:

```
0x0000000000400595 <+35>:   movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
```

which is where I think the `x = 1` instruction is. I've written the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn(int a, int b, int c) {
  char buf1[5];
  char buf2[10];
  int *ret;

  ret = buf1 + 24;
  (*ret) += 7;
}

int main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  fn(1, 2, 3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

and disassembled it in gdb. I have disabled address randomization and compiled the program with the `-fno-stack-protector` option.

#### Question 1

I can see from the disassembler output below that I want to skip past the instruction at address `0x0000000000400595`: both the return address from `callq <fn>` and the address of the `movl` instruction. Therefore, if the return address is `0x0000000000400595`, and the next instruction is `0x000000000040059c`, I should add 7 bytes to the return address?

```
0x0000000000400572 <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400573 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400576 <+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x000000000040057a <+8>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400581 <+15>:   mov    $0x3,%edx
0x0000000000400586 <+20>:   mov    $0x2,%esi
0x000000000040058b <+25>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
0x0000000000400590 <+30>:   callq  0x40052d <fn>
0x0000000000400595 <+35>:   movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
0x000000000040059c <+42>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x000000000040059f <+45>:   mov    %eax,%esi
0x00000000004005a1 <+47>:   mov    $0x40064a,%edi
0x00000000004005a6 <+52>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004005ab <+57>:   callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
0x00000000004005b0 <+62>:   leaveq 
0x00000000004005b1 <+63>:   retq
```

#### Question 2

I notice that I can add 5 bytes to the return address in place of 7 and achieve the same result. When I do so, am I not jumping into the middle of the instruction `0x0000000000400595 <+35>:   movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)`? In which case, why does this not crash the program, like when I add 6 bytes to the return address in place of 5 bytes or 7 bytes.

#### Question 3

> Just before buffer1[] on the stack is SFP, and before it, the return address.
>   That is 4 bytes pass the end of buffer1[].  But remember that buffer1[] is
>   really 2 word so its 8 bytes long.  So the return address is 12 bytes from
>   the start of buffer1[].

In the example by Aleph 1, he/she calculates the offset of the return address as 12 bytes from the start of buffer1[]. Since I am on x86_64, and not x86_32, I need to recalculate the offset to the return address. When on x86_64, is it the case that buffer1[] is still 2 words, which is 16 bytes; and the SFP and return address are 8 bytes each (as we're on 64 bit) and therefore the return address is at: `buf1 + (8 * 2) + 8` which is equivalent to `buf1 + 24`?

Comment: Related to [Memory alignment today and 20 years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30222214/1708801) may be helpful in understanding what has changed since then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, and very important, thing to note: all numbers and offsets are very compiler-dependent. Different compilers, and even the same compiler with different settings, can produce drastically different assemblies. For example, many compilers can (and will) remove `buf2` because it's not used. They can also remove `x = 0` as its effect is not used and later overwritten. They can also remove `x = 1` and replace all occurences of `x` with a constant `1`, etc, etc.

That said, you absolutely need to make numbers for a specific assembly you're getting on your specific compiler and its settings.

**Question 1**
Since you provided the assembly for `main()`, I can confirm that you need to add 7 bytes to the return address, which would normally be `0x0000000000400595`, to skip over `x=1` and go to `0x000000000040059c` which loads `x` into register for later use. `0x000000000040059c - 0x0000000000400595 = 7`.

**Question 2**
Adding just 5 bytes instead of 7 will indeed jump into middle of instruction. However, this 2-byte tail of instruction happen (by pure chance) to be another valid instruction code. This is why it doesn't crash.

**Question 3**
This is again very compiler and settings dependent. Pretty much everything can happen there. Since you didn't provide disassembly, I can only **make guesses**. The guess would be the following: `buf` and `buf2` are rounded up to the next stack unit boundary (8 bytes on x64). `buf` becomes 8 bytes, and `buf2` becomes 16 bytes. Frame pointers are not saved to stack on x64, so no "SFP". That's 24 bytes total.